# Orleans Extension not installed

Tags: c#, reactive-programming, orleans

I'm starting to dive into the Orleans Streams and I'm running into an issue using ImplicitStreamSubscription. I'm building upon the [QuickStart](http://dotnet.github.io/orleans/Orleans-Streams/Streams-Quick-Start) example by adding a new project that implements both the interfaces and the grains. Here is the all of the code I have so far in my grains.

```
[ImplicitStreamSubscription("RANDOMDATA")]
public class VSMDiscovery : Grain, IVSMDiscovery
{
    public override Task OnActivateAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Started" + this.GetPrimaryKey());

        return base.OnActivateAsync();
    }
}

public interface IVSMDiscovery : IGrainWithIntegerKey
{
}
```

In the DevTest main, I simply send an event using

```
 var guid = Guid.NewGuid();

 //Get one of the providers which we defined in config
 var streamProvider = Orleans.GrainClient.GetStreamProvider("SMSProvider");

 //Get the reference to a stream
 var stream = streamProvider.GetStream<int>(guid, "RANDOMDATA");

 stream.OnNextAsync(1);
```

Everything seems to execute fine, a new grain is instantiated and OnActivateAsync is called which writes the message to the console, however I get this error.

> VSM Started206d105b-d21b-496c-997a-9dac3cf370b3
>   Extension not installed on grain Draco.VSMConnection.VSMDiscovery attempting to invoke type Orleans.Streams.OrleansCodeGenStreamConsumerExtensionMethodInvoker from invokable Orleans.Runtime.ActivationData
>   Exception = Orleans.Runtime.GrainExtensionNotInstalledException: Extension not installed on grain Draco.VSMConnection.VSMDiscovery attempting to invoke type Orleans.Streams.OrleansCodeGenStreamConsumerExtensionMethodInvoker from invokable Orleans.Runtime.ActivationData
>
> [2016-03-09 05:53:41.007 GMT    14      WARNING 103405  InsideRuntimeClient     127.0.0.1:11111]    Extension not installed on grain Draco.VSMConnection.VSMDiscovery attempting to invoke type Orleans.Streams.OrleansCodeGenStreamConsumerExtensionMethodInvoker from invokable Orleans.Runtime.ActivationData for message NewPlacement Request S127.0.0.1:11111:195198808*cli/5853f180@9c59fabf->S127.0.0.1:11111:195198808*grn/EB2C0203/ac9d7a99@0e33939b #5: global::Orleans.Streams.IStreamConsumerExtension:DeliverItem()

As I mentioned, everything appears to be running ok, but having this error is very concerning. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've faced the same issue. Could you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

For me, this was caused by having a grain which had an implicit subscription attribute, but which FORGOT to subscribe to the stream in the OnActiveAsync method (which is required and is outlined in the quick start mentioned above).... not clear from the error message at all.  Hope this saves someone else some pain.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the "SMSProvider" stream provider is correctly specified in the config file, for both client and silo, like here: https://github.com/dotnet/orleans/blob/master/test/Tester/OrleansConfigurationForStreamingUnitTests.xml#L9

Comment: signalling that link is broken :)